# Fundamental principle of counting in bench seating choice preferences in a subway

Tags: combinatorics

A subway car has $10$ individual seats, with $5$ in front and $5$ in back. From $10$ ​passengers, $4$ prefers front seat, $3$ prefers back seat and the others have no preference. In how many ways can passengers be seated, respecting preferences?

**Attempt:** I want to solve using only the notion of Fundamental principle of counting:

Let $F$ be each of the $4$ passengers who want to sit in the front, $N$ the passengers who have no preference, and $C$ the passengers who want to sit back. Now, since we have $3 \dot 2$ possibilities to take a passenger without preference (it will be multiplied by the final result) we will take one of the passengers $N$ to sit in the front seat, we will have, by the multiplicative principle: $$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

Now $N-1=2$ passengers without preference are left, and they will be exchanged with passengers who want to sit back: $$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

But if you go on like that, and at the end of it all, multiplying it by $6$ I don't get the right result. What am I wrong?

The answer is $43200$

Comment: Not sure how you got $32$ possibilities to take a passenger without a preference. There are three passengers without a preference, and so there are three ways to choose one (to sit on the front seat). Once chosen, multiply that with $5!=5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=120$ ways to seat the passengers on the front seats, and again by $5!=120$ to seat the passengers on the back seat. The result is $3\cdot 120^2=43200$.

Comment: You only need to choose *one* person with no preference (in $3$ ways) to go on the front seat. This automatically and uniquely chooses the *other two* people with no preference to go to the back seats. The different ordering of all of those people on the seats is then accounted for in the multiplication by $5!$ (twice).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I understand your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Front row seating - Once you have chosen a person with no preference to seat along with $4$ persons who prefer front row, there are $5!$ ways to seat them as you counted.

Back row seating - for remaining $5$ including $3$ who prefer to sit in the back row, there is again $5!$ ways to seat them as you counted correctly.

The *only* part that you missed is to choose one of the three persons with no preference for the front row.

So the answer should be $ ~3 \cdot 5! \cdot 5! = 43200$

---

Another approach for counting can be to seat $4$ people with front row preference and $3$ people with back row preference. Then seat rest $3$ folks in remaining seats.

$ \displaystyle {5 \choose 4} \cdot 4! \cdot {5 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 3! = 43200$

Comment: Since there are $3$ ways to choose the first one, why wouldn't I have $2$ ways to choose the second pass without preference?

Comment: @Behemooth but you are arranging them as part of $5!$. You have $3$ people with preference and remaining $2$ without preference for the back seats. You are arranging them in $5!$ ways in back seats.

Answer (score 1):

Isn’t it just $P(5,4) \times P(5,3) \times (10-4-3)! $ ? where $P$ means permutations.

The method in the OP just confuses me and I don’t understand what the OP is trying.